# Why is '#define alloc_nr(x) (((x)+16)*3/2)' macro used in many cache.h files?

Tags: c++, c, git, caching, macros

I've seen the below macro used in a lot of cache.h files:

```
#define alloc_nr(x) (((x)+16)*3/2)
```

[Here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/util/cache.h#L38) is one example.

I know it's used to increase allocated buffer size when the buffer is almost full. The buffer would grow by roughly 1.5 times its current size. That's why `*3/2` is used. But why an extra `16` is added? The macro became `x*1.5+24` when it's expanded. Is there any particular reason for this macro? Why everyone likes to use this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the initial value is 0, you want `alloc_nr(0)` to give a strictly positive number (24 here). Without the `16` it would be 0. You want `alloc_nr(x)`to be greater than `x` (and not too near of `x` to avoid too frequent reallocations).

The particular numbers `16` and `3` and `2`  are not very important (the ratio `3/2` is more significant).

Comment: thanks very much! It's used to make the buffer grow quicker in the beginning.

Comment: do you know what does `nr` mean in `alloc_nr`? number?

Answer (score 3):

This will probably help (from http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/util/cache.h#L38)

```
41  * Realloc the buffer pointed at by variable 'x' so that it can hold
42  * at least 'nr' entries; the number of entries currently allocated
43  * is 'alloc', using the standard growing factor alloc_nr() macro.
44  *
45  * DO NOT USE any expression with side-effect for 'x' or 'alloc'.
46  */
47 #define ALLOC_GROW(x, nr, alloc) \
48         do { \
49                 if ((nr) > alloc) { \
50                         if (alloc_nr(alloc) < (nr)) \
51                                 alloc = (nr); \
52                         else \
53                                 alloc = alloc_nr(alloc); \
54                         x = xrealloc((x), alloc * sizeof(*(x))); \
55                 } \
56         } while(0)
57
```

You understand the `*3/2`. The `+16` is ensuring it grows at least by 16 objects (whatever `sizeof *x` is) when the buffer is small. There's a balance to be struck in not wasting too much memory, and avoiding too many individual `realloc`s. When the buffer is small, wasting 'large multiples' of the buffer memory is not an issue. For instance, if it just used `*3/2`, an 4 object buffer would only grow to 6 objects. In particular, without this growing a zero entry buffer would not actually grow it at all. Far better to waste some space and grow it quicker (in relative terms) when the buffer is small.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helps a lot. Now i can understand the code better, it's really great design for me. :-)

Comment: do you know what does `nr` mean in `alloc_nr`? number?

Comment: I'd guess so. I think it comes from the `nr` parameter to `ALLOC_GROW`.